# Find short similar sequences in long time series

Tags: machine-learning, similarity

Input data is a short time series, and I want to find a scalable short series that looks like the input from a long time series, should I use the sliding window, or do you have any better suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Can you clearly divide the short sequences or are they merged together?

If they have a clear time division (ex: a day or a week), you can set a batch of a short time and learn every short sequence correctly.

Otherwise, you have to find ways to cut the short sequences correctly without overlapping each other.

In both cases, you can detect short sequences' shapes thanks to 2D CNN for instance.

https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-use-convolutional-neural-networks-for-time-series-classification-56b1b0a07a57

Comment: Does it answer your question? If not, please let me know.